# after multiplication with two variables then how to display result of that when tab press

Tags: c#

after multiplication with two variables in c sharp then how to display the  result of that when tab press.

Comment: You have to specify which ui you are using. Windows Forms, WPF, Webforms, something else?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of c# you can use javascript onkeypress() or onchange() action, because it display the result when tab press.